# PARTITION BY alternative in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb, window-functions

I would like to fire the query suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800572/2968357 on a HSQLDB database using **select *** such as

```
WITH tmpTable AS (
SELECT p.* ,
        ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY p.groupColumn order by p.groupColumn desc) AS rowCount
  FROM sourceTable p) SELECT * FROM  tmpTable WHERE tmpTable.rowCount = 1
```

but getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: PARTITION required: )
```

meaning **PARTITION BY** is not supported.

Is there a work-around for my specific query on HSQLDB?

Comment: Use the part of that answer with the heading **Supported by any database**

Comment: Thanks, but how do i accomplish the select * statement i just added to my question?

Comment: The CTE (WITH .. AS) query is not necessary unless you use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION .. syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The second query in that answer is supported by HSQLDB. If you use the HSQLDB DatabaseManager and the `insert test data` from its `options` menu, you get tables that are populated with data and are suitable for this type of query.

```
SELECT MIN(x.id),  
     x.customerID, 
     x.total
FROM INVOICE x
JOIN (SELECT p.customerID,
             MAX(total) AS max_total
        FROM INVOICE p
    GROUP BY p.customerID) y ON y.customerID = x.customerID
                          AND y.max_total = x.total
GROUP BY x.customerID, x.total
```

But when you want to select from two tables, there is an interesting alternative in HSQLDB that performs quite well:

```
SELECT INV.* FROM CUSTOMER, 
LATERAL (SELECT ID, CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME, TOTAL 
FROM INVOICE  
WHERE CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.ID 
ORDER BY TOTAL, ID LIMIT 1) INV
```

This query returns a result like this:

```
ID CUSTOMERID FIRSTNAME TOTAL   
-- ---------- --------- ------- 
1  0          Laura     2700.90 
36 1          Robert    4761.60 
27 3          Michael   3420.30 
12 4          Bill      3867.30
```