# In-memory database alternative to HSQL which supports Partition By Query

Tags: java, hsqldb, in-memory-database, partition-by

Working on Spring boot application test-cases. Was mocking Oracle database using hsql in-memory database but found it doesn't support partition by query and fails with below error:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: PARTITION required: )
```

Had checked [Partition by modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737540/partition-by-alternative-in-hsqldb) but I don't want to modify my queries but use that database which support my queries.

Which alternative database will work here?

Comment: Did you know about h2? But ```H2 doesn't have any automatic data partitioning support.```

Comment: If it doesn't support partition then its of no use to me.

Answer (score -1):

The HyperXtrmeSQL database is based on HSQLDB and supports OVER(PARTIION ...) syntax. See http://hyperxtreme.co.uk/features.html (disclaimer: I am the developer)

Comment: Thanks Fredt. But as I see its not free but paid software/library. I did't find link for downloading the jar or it's maven/gradle coordinates. Can you help me with this.